# Operation Inside a Dataframe

Tags: r

I'm working on the following df:

```
Num1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2)
Num2 <- c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,4, 4)
Num3 <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7)
Num4 <- c(1, 3, 3, 1, 2,3, 3, 6)
Num5 <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1)
df <- data.frame(Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5)
```

I need to create a new matrix having the first column as `df[1] - df[2]`,  the second as  `df[2] - df[3]`  and so on.

Comment: You should use a matrix, not a data.frame, if all your cols are numeric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
mapply('-', df[-length(df)], df[-1])
```

Or (as mentioned by @Pierre Lafortune)

```
df[-length(df)] - df[-1]
```

Comment: I believe @PierreLafortune's method is even simpler, thus, better.

Comment: Also, `-t(diff(t(df)))`